# Java - programming a two-way console window

Tags: java, console

I am interested in creating a text-based game in Java and am wondering how I would replicate the common server console (ie: nogui server mode in the minecraft-server for example) - as in there is always a line at the bottom of the console for input, and everything else above it is output which can be written to asynchronously.

How would I get started on this? I am unfamiliar with the terminology regarding this sort of stuff and also what libraries to use to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look to [Java curses library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/). I haven't use it but, it looks like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This library may well be helpful: I created it in order to implement a small Rogelike game in Java:

- https://github.com/mikera/swing-console

It uses Swing to create a simulated console-style window.

Comment: This seems ideal. Could you compile this as a library .jar file for use? I'm having problems doing that myself.

Comment: Latest compiled versions are available on clojars: https://clojars.org/repo/net/mikera/swing-console/