# How to move java print lines to the top of the console window?

Tags: java, linux, console

I'm making java app. which runs on the console. I'm currently implementing a command similar to `clear` in Linux.

I found a way to clear the console through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888362/commands-in-java-to-clear-the-screen)

I'm using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4888438)

The problem, however, is that the current line does not move up to become the top line. What happens is that every line above the current line gets cleared but the current remains where it is.

How do I move the current line to become the first line --- be on the top?

Comment: Perhaps you want to look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619676/java-programming-a-two-way-console-window?rq=1
If using Java curses is an overkill, you could consult its source code.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.print("\f");
Prints a formfeed, which clears the screen and moves the cursor to the top.